# Is there a browser-sync option to open Google Chrome in incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome, gulp, browser-sync, incognito-mode

I've taken a look at the [documentation](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-browser) but it's a little thin on what values are acceptable. Does anyone know if there's a value to open Google Chrome incognito and/or have a complete list (who knows I might want to open a project in IE/Edge one day).

I've tried:

- browser: "google chrome -incognito"
- browser: "-incognito"
- browser: "incognito"

Not many more alternatives, I reckon.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's command line switch is actually --incognito (two dashes), but I tried it in my browsersync Gulp task and that didn't work.

The workaround I'm using is to use a Chrome extension to switch my development domain name to incognito. It looks like there are a couple extensions that do that, I use Ghost Incognito:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghost-incognito/gedeaafllmnkkgbinfnleblcglamgebg?hl=en-US

Answer (score 0):

in general, I created a shortcut to launch the browser in private mode. then in browser-sync settings added parameter:

```
browser: 'absolute path to shortcut'
```

Hurrah!